# Molar heat capacity and heat capacity

Tags: physical-chemistry, terminology, notation

Is molar heat capacity and heat capacity

1. at constant volume both represented by $C_v$?
2. at constant pressure both represented by $C_p$?

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately, we use usually use the same symbol for both.  The context of the problem and solution determines which one is being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbols, which are standardized in [ISO/IEC 80000 Quantities and units (14 parts)](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=46202) and recommended by IUPAC in [Quantities, Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry (Green Book)](http://www.iupac.org/home/publications/e-resources/nomenclature-and-terminology/quantities-units-and-symbols-in-physical-chemistry-green-book.html), distinguish the various related quantities:

$$\small
\begin{array}{llll}
\hline
\text{Quantity} & \text{Quantity} & \text{Unit} & \text{Unit} \\
\text{name} & \text{symbol} & \text{name} & \text{symbol} \\
\hline
\text{heat capacity} & C & \text{joule per kelvin} & \mathrm{J/K} \\
\text{heat capacity at constant pressure} & C_p & \text{joule per kelvin} & \mathrm{J/K} \\
\text{heat capacity at constant volume} & C_V & \text{joule per kelvin} & \mathrm{J/K} \\
\text{specific heat capacity} & c & \text{joule per kilogram kelvin} & \mathrm{J/( kg \cdot K )} \\
\text{specific heat capacity at constant pressure} & c_p & \text{joule per kilogram kelvin} & \mathrm{J/( kg \cdot K )} \\
\text{specific heat capacity at constant volume} & c_V & \text{joule per kilogram kelvin} & \mathrm{J/( kg \cdot K )} \\
\text{molar heat capacity} & C_\mathrm m & \text{joule per mole kelvin} & \mathrm{J/( mol \cdot K )} \\
\text{molar heat capacity at constant pressure} & C_{\mathrm m, p} & \text{joule per mole kelvin} & \mathrm{J/( mol \cdot K )} \\
\text{molar heat capacity at constant volume} & C_{\mathrm m, V} & \text{joule per mole kelvin} & \mathrm{J/( mol \cdot K )} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

However, in contrast to symbols for units, symbols for quantities are only recommendations. Unfortunately, quantity symbols are used inconsistently in the literature, sometimes in a sloppy way. In principle, a given symbol can indicate different quantities.